# How to execute forge watch

Tags: wordpress, forge

Hi everyone I try to use forge to generate a template for wordpress

I install forge, create a link and, when I execute forge watch  and I obtain this error....

```
/Users/local/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/guard-1.3.3/lib/guard.rb:47:in `setup': uninitialized constant Listen::Turnstile (NameError)
```

any idea, how to solver the error.

any idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, try this:

1. Uninstall your current listen gem. 
   gem uninstall listen
2. Intall listen gem version "0.4.2"
   gem install listen -v "0.4.2"

It will be enough to resolve the problem.